# Django admin appears broken

Tags: python, django

This screenshot show the problem i am having. However, when you minimize window, the page is displayed normally.[enter image description here
This is my code in admin.py:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Actualité

# Register your models here.
class ActualitéAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('id','titre','contenu','date_de_publication')

admin.site.register(Actualité, ActualitéAdmin)
```

when I launch django and I enter the Actualité page mentioned in admin.py it shows me this interface on the page :
[django admin page appears broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLA96.png)

This is a code in console :

```
 [08/Sep/2022 11:16:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3701
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:36] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:36] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11383
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:36] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 439
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:36] "GET /static/css/admin.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:37] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 334
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:37] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 383
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:37] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:39] "GET /admin/Actualit%C3%A9/actualit%C3%A9/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11697
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:39] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7953
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:39] "GET /static/css/admin.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798
[08/Sep/2022 11:16:39] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 371
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include the error you are facing either it be a traceback or image to show the error response. We can't give you any answers without the basic problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your static file rendering. You should type the following in the terminal:

```bash
python manage.py collectstatic
```

If this doesn't solve your problem try deleting the static files first and then collectstatic again.

Comment: if this solved your query, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I just found the answer, just add : " admin.autodiscover() " and " admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False " in the urls.py file so that the display is clean on the django admin side. I hope that it can help others in the same case as me